# How to express "my name used online"?

Tags: word-request

I've come up with these ideas:

- My name online
- My online name
- My web name

"My name used online" is too long for me and I think there must be a shorter alternative.

But I cannot decide on one. Is there any convention about that?

Comment: "My online name" sounds better than others, but I don't really know if there are official conventions for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My **username** from the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/username) is

> An identification used by a person with access to a computer, network,
>   or online service.

So

> My username is **Weather Vane**

Answer (score 1):

The noun **[handle](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=handle)** can be used to refer to a nickname, particularly one used on online forums.

> b. An alternate name or nickname, especially one chosen for self-identification on online forums or citizens band radio.

(American Heritage Dictionary)